# How do you set up an Ecto changeset to prevent models missing required fields from being saved?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

According to the Phoenix documentation:

> insert(Ecto.Schema.t | Ecto.Changeset.t, Keyword.t) ::   {:ok,
>   Ecto.Schema.t} |   {:error, Ecto.Changeset.t}
>
> Inserts a model or a changeset.
>
> In case a model is given, the model is converted into a changeset with
>   all model non-virtual fields as part of the changeset. This conversion
>   is done by calling Ecto.Changeset.change/2 directly.
>
> In case a changeset is given, the changes in the changeset are merged
>   with the model fields, and all of them are sent to the database.
>
> If any before_insert or after_insert callback is registered in the
>   given model, they will be invoked with the changeset.
>
> It returns {:ok, model} if the model has been successfully inserted or
>   {:error, changeset} if there was a validation or a known constraint
>   error.

### What I did

```
defmodule Dollar.User do
    use Dollar.Web, :model

    schema "users" do
        field :username, :string
        field :sms_number, :string
        field :email, :string

        timestamps
    end

    @required_fields ~w(sms_number)
    @optional_fields ~w(username email)

    @doc """
    Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.
    If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
    with no validation performed.
    """
    def changeset(user, params \\ :empty) do
        user
        |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
        |> validate_length(:sms_number, is: 10)
        |> unique_constraint(:sms_number)
        |> unique_constraint(:username)
    end
end
```

### What I expected

```
Repo.insert(%User{})
=> {:error, ... }
```

I expected an error because the `sms_number` is **required**.

### What I actually got

```sh
[debug] INSERT INTO "users" ("inserted_at", "updated_at", "email", "sms_number", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" [{{2016, 3, 19}, {15, 13, 5, 0}}, {{2016, 3, 19}, {15, 13, 5, 0}}, nil, nil, nil] OK query=1.5ms
%Dollar.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, email: nil, id: 7,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-03-19T15:13:05Z>, sms_number: nil,
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-03-19T15:13:05Z>, username: nil}
```

The record is stored in the database

### Environment

- Elixir 1.2.3
- Ecto 1.1.4
- Phoenix Ecto 2.0.1
- Phoenix 1.1.4

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are trying to directly insert struct defined in model the `changeset` function is not called at all. `%User{}` is only a struct from a module and ecto does not know anything about functions defined in this module. You can delete `changeset` function and `Repo.insert` will still work.

`changeset` function is your custom validation code. The docs you have pasted state that another function is called instead: `Ecto.Changeset.change/2`. It creates a changeset that is valid by default and non of the fields are required.

You can try it yourself:

```
changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change %User{}
changeset.required # []
changeset.valid?   # true
new_changeset = User.changeset changeset
new_changeset.required # [:sms_number]
new_changeset.valid?   # false
```

Always run your custom validations before inserting to database and use `Repo.insert` with a changeset instead of raw struct. It is probably also a good idea to enforce required fields on the database itself with not null constraint in your migration:

```
add :username, :string, null: false
```

Comment: Looks like I made a rookie mistake. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: And you're right about the ```null``` option for the field in my schema. I had in mind to add this later.